# Как перенести базу Mysql(InnoDB) из MariaDB в Percona XtraDB?

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, percona

Есть база (около 57Гб), крутится в MariaDB 10.1 Нужно перенести ее в Percona XtraDB (будет крутиться там в состае Galera кластер, но это потом, главное перенести базу хотя бы на одну ноду). Встал вопрос как это сделать максимально быстро. mysqldump работает отлично, но залив дампа идет около 6 часов - слишком долго. При попытке делать потоковый дамп

mysqldump --single-transaction DB | mysql --host=IP -uUSER -pPASS -C DB

- скорость такая же. Очень быстро делается бекап через xtrabackup (он же innobackupex), но вот беда, получившийся бекап не подходит к Percona - жалуется на кучу несовместимостей базы mysql, perfomance schema и прочее. Что делать, товарищи? Очень критично переехать быстро, с минимальным простоем.

Comment: А почему нельзя сделать экспорт в CSV, а потом - мпортировать? Типа вот так http://infobsd.ru/content/eksport-tablicy-mysql-v-csv-fayl  Думаю, это самый быстрый вариант.

Comment: Мне кажется, сыроватый метод - нужно писать скрипт, обходящий все таблицы (это, конечно, нетрудно) - и потом как это импортировать обратно? Почему должен быть прирост относительно mysqldump - вроде он работает сходным образом (ну разве что все таблицы, а то и все базы он помещает в один файл)?

Comment: Я не уверен, время не замерял, но мне кажется, что здесь должен работать один из основных принципов программирования: самое простое решение - самое правильное в 75% случаев. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Исправлять базы mysql, perfomance schema и прочее. Заменяя при остановленном mysql таблицы теми что при установке создаются. Ну и пользователей перезавести прийдется. Там несовместимость по таблице пользователей.
Недавно этим методом именно марии в перкону смигрировал данные.